# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '.00' to data type int

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This statement needs to output the # of days absent + '.00'. Currently the statement works to return a value of 500 if the student was absent 5 days. I need the output be formatted like 5.00. My issue is that every time I add the decimal '.00' to this statement I get:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '.00' to data type int.

Again it runs fine without the period. How do I cast this statement to include the period and return both statements as int so they can be subtracted from one another?

```
Cast(cast(left(ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar,(select CONVERT(int,(SUM(dayenrolled))) from attsum         
        where suniq = sd.suniq and trkuniq = ss.trkuniq and ddate between ss.edate and ISNULL(ss.xdate,GETDATE()))),'')+'.00',5)as varchar(6)) as int)       
    -
    Cast(cast(Left(ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar,(select CONVERT(int,(SUM(dayapportion))) from attsum         
        where suniq = sd.suniq and trkuniq = ss.trkuniq and ddate between ss.edate and ISNULL(ss.xdate,GETDATE()))),'')+'.00',5)as varchar(6))as int)[ESSA # Days Absent],
        --Statement needs a period to output .00 left of the # of days absent and to start on line 2.
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more context, like the data structure and your query? Right now this is pretty confusing. Clearly anyhting with decimals isn't an int though.

Comment: 5.00 is not an integer.  It's a float or a decimal.

Comment: How can you get an `INT` (by definition without fractional part) and get `.00` at the same time? Try `CAST(mycolumn AS DECIMAL(10,2))`

Comment: Good point about decimal as int. I tried float and decimal as data types for the bulk of my query and the .00 did not show up. I will try that a little more. My other thought is to dump the original output into a lookup table to calculate as int and then format it to decimal when I call it back into the stored procedure. But I will try some of your suggestions first.

Comment: I think you need to rewrite that statement from scratch because it will be a nightmare to maintain. Even now it doesn't make sense, if I've read the first statement right you have an int that you convert to a varchar, then you add '.00' to that varchar take the 5 leftmost characters and cast them to a varchar(6) which you cast to an int. It's very weird-

Comment: Please study up on [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql). It explains what happens when you mix types, e.g. strings and integers.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put the SQL Statement, but I guess this way will work for you:

```
SELECT VALUE/100 FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what your database/table looks like, I would say you should change the data type of your field in your table from `int` to `float` or `decimal`.  This should give you what you desire without the need for extra query logic or math.

Answer (score 0):

The approach is:

```
1.  cast the integer to a string
2.  right trim the string (if necessary)
3.  concatenate '.00' to the end of the string.
```

The specifics depend on the database engine, but here is a sql server example

```
select cast(5 as varchar(15)) + '.00'
```

In this case, since I casted to a varchar, it wasn't necessary to trim it.

Answer (score 0):

convert your final value to decimal . cast(  as decimal(18,2))